# Tkinter, how to make a calculation button from the entries?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

First of all, my code has to be in greek(these are some means of transportation, e.g. buses, semitrucks, cars etc) so Im sorry in advance. Here is the thing: I want the user to enter in the entries how many vehicles of each kind exist (variables of my Traffic_Volume function) and after he/she presses the Calculate button to get the result(calculations between entries and numbers).

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 600
root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Κυκλοφοριακός Φόρτος", fg="black")
label.place(relwidth=1.0)

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Είδος Οχήματος")
label.place(relx=0, rely=0.1)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="Λεωφορεία")
label.place(relx=0, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="Ημιφορτηγά")
label.place(relx=0, rely=0.30, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="Φορτηγά")
label.place(relx=0, rely=0.40, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="Συρόμενα")
label.place(relx=0, rely=0.50, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="Άλλα")
label.place(relx=0, rely=0.60, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="Ι.Χ.")
label.place(relx=0, rely=0.70, relwidth=0.15)

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Αριθμός Αξόνων")
label.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="2 ή 3 άξονες")
label.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="2 άξονες")
label.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.30, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="3 άξονες")
label.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.40, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="4+ άξονες")
label.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.50, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="2 άξονες")
label.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.60, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="N/A")
label.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.70, relwidth=0.15)

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Συντελεστής Ισοδυναμίας")
label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.10, relwidth=0.25)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="1.30")
label.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.20, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="0.34")
label.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.30, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="1.50")
label.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.40, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="3.025")
label.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.50, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="0.026")
label.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.60, relwidth=0.15)
label = tk.Label(frame, text="0.00")
label.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.70, relwidth=0.15)

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Αριθμός οχημάτων")
label.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.10, relwidth=0.20)
entry_1 = tk.Entry(frame, bg="white")
entry_1.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.20, relwidth=0.20)
entry_2 = tk.Entry(frame, bg="white")
entry_2.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.30, relwidth=0.20)
entry_3 = tk.Entry(frame, bg="white")
entry_3.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.40, relwidth=0.20)
entry_4 = tk.Entry(frame, bg="white")
entry_4.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.50, relwidth=0.20)
entry_5 = tk.Entry(frame, bg="white")
entry_5.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.60, relwidth=0.20)
entry_6 = tk.Entry(frame, bg="white")
entry_6.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.70, relwidth=0.20)

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Ποσοστό Κυκλοφορίας στη Λωρίδα Μελέτης(ΠΚΛΜ)")
label.place(relx=0, rely=0.8)
entry_7 = tk.Entry(frame)
entry_7.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.8)

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Διάρκεια Σχεδιασμού(σε n έτη)")
label.place(relx=0, rely=0.85)
n = entry_7 = tk.Entry(frame)
n = entry_7.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.85)

label = tk.Label(frame, text="Μέση Ετήσια Αύξηση της Κυκλοφορίας(r σε δεκαδική μορφή)")
label.place(relx=0, rely=0.9)
r = entry_8 = tk.Entry(frame)
r = entry_8.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.9)


def Traffic_Volume():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Result", "Message goes here")
    float((entry_1 * 1.30 + entry_2 * 0.34 + entry_3 * 1.50 + entry_4 * 3.025 + entry_5 * 0.026 + entry_6 * 0.00) * entry_7 * 365 * ((1 - r) ** n) - 1) / r))
    return


button = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate Traffic Volume", command=Traffic_Volume)
button.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

Anyways, thanks in advance, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand... You got entries, and then, the user puts values inside entries, and you wanna get this ? There is a simple thing : str(your_entry.get()) will give you the string inside the entry at the exact moment you call it. If you do it again, it will actualise, so you can set this as your command of a button.

Comment: @TheMachinist: you don't need to wrap `your_entry.get()` inside `str()`.  The contents of entry widgets are strings.

Comment: so could you, please,  type exactly what will the final code have to be in order to work, because this is my first python project and I know very basic things?

Comment: @BryanOakley oh yeah that's !False :3